# Spring FilterChain + Security: log request with user or not

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring web-mvc REST-service with several initializers.

`WebAppInitializer.java`

```
@Order(1)
public class MyFiltersInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addFilter("myRequestFilter", DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
        // register other filters and DispatcherServlet
    }
}
```

`SecurityWebAppInitializer.java`

```
@Order(2)
public class MySecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Set<SessionTrackingMode> getSessionTrackingModes() {
        return EnumSet.of(SessionTrackingMode.COOKIE, SessionTrackingMode.URL);
    }
}
```

As you can see, `SecurityFilterChain` is being added after all custom request filters. What I need to do is to **log every request, and include `User` to log, if request is authorized**

Something like `MyRequestFilter.java`:

```
@Slf4j
public class RequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request,
                                    final HttpServletResponse response,
                                    final FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
           MyUser user = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal(); //no auth yet
           log.debug("request {} start, user {}", request, user); 
           filterChain.doFilter(request, response); //may return 401 or 403, what also need to be logged
           log.debug("request {} end with response {}", request, response);
   }
```

There is an idea to add an `LogBodyHolder`, which keeps log body until `SecurityChain` is passed completely, and then call `log.debug`. But is there any **pretty** way to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by *pretty way*?

Comment: Which logging framework is it used? In log4j there is a logging context which could be used to store information needed to be included in each line of the logs. Check [Improved Java Logging with Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC)](https://www.baeldung.com/mdc-in-log4j-2-logback). Though it might be off topic as I'm not sure I completely understood the question

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a Spring Bean that extends the class `AbstractRequestLoggingFilter` which is provided by Spring and then override the `beforeRequest()` and `afterRequest()` methods to add your logs as you wish.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but it's not quite the logic I am looking for. What I need is a **single** log per request, containing all the info it was able to collect during request. My app has a filter, that can clear `SecurityContext` event though it was initialized earlier. For now the solution is to make a queue storing request info until the request is done and `FilterChain` is fully completed. It seems to be the obvious way to solve this problem, but maybe there are standard tools or patterns.